# Error starting Juggernaut

Tags: node.js, redis, juggernaut

When I try to start Juggernaut I get this error :

```
1 Apr 20:21:01 - socket.io ready - accepting connections
node_redis: no callback to send error: ERR unknown command 'subscribe'

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: ERR unknown command 'subscribe'
    at RedisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.5.9/packag
e/index.js:84:27)
    at RedisReplyParser.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at RedisReplyParser.send_error (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.5.9/package
/lib/parser/javascript.js:251:14)
    at RedisReplyParser.execute (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.5.9/package/li
b/parser/javascript.js:110:22)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.5.9/package/index.j
s:328:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.5.9/package/index.js
:99:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:672:14)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
```

I didnt find anything to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading [Redis](http://redis.io).

It happened to me, and that's what solved it. I'm using Ubuntu, and the one in the package manager isn't an updated version. It needs to be at least version 2.2.1.

Source: [From one of the issues posted on the juggernaut github repo.](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut/issues/56)

**EDIT:** Upon closer inspection, it looks like you were the one who posted the issue on the github repo. I'll just leave this answer here just in case anyone else has the same problem.